# Copy the values from a variable?

Tags: variables

I set a variable `b:aaa` which has the value that I can see via `echo b:aaa`, how can I copy that to text? I know I can do it by

```
set @a = b:aaa
"ap
```

to get it. But can I copy it to the an open file directly?

Comment: Copy to what text?  It's all text.  If you mean using it in insert mode: `<c-r>=b:aaa`

Comment: @TommyA I'd like to accept your answer.

Comment: @TommyA What if `b:aaa` is not a string, for instance a dict(which should be transfered to string via `string(b:aaa)`)?

Comment: That's a technical detail that's left to you.  But yes, wrapping it in `string()` would add safety.

Comment: Are you just wanting to put the contents of a variable into a buffer? e.g. `:put=b:aaa`

Comment: Additionaly see `getreg()` and `setreg()` functions for setting the register to a specific value. And also see `:h let-option` for setting the option to a variable.

Comment: @PeterRincker Exactly.

Comment: @TommyA After pressing <c-r> it goes to the command mode, thus it is easy to wrap it in string(). That's awesome!

Comment: Since it seems we're just listing the different ways to do this, it should be noted that `:put=` also accepts a list of lines and is _always_ `linewise`.

Answer (score 4):

To put the value of a variable into a buffer use the `:put` command with the expression register, `@=`:

```
put=b:aaa
```

You can use a range with `:put` to put it at a specific location. Put below the 9th line:

```
9put=b:aaa
```

Note: use `:put!` to put above the current line

For more help see:

```
:h :put
:h @=
:h :range
```

Answer (score 1):

Registers works like variables, so you are almost done. I think this would work for you:

```
let @a = b:aaa
"ap
```

Comment: Better use `setreg()` function.

Comment: I didn't know about the setreg() function, it seems to be more functional because allow line wise and block wise selection. Also the `:put ` solution Peter Rincker mentions is good

Comment: Why is `setreg()` better @ChristianBrabandt? I thought it just existed to support things like `setreg(l:some_var, "val")`?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker because you can force the register to actually behave like linewise, characterwise or blockwise